# Numpy method doesn't show up

Tags: python, numpy

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
newarr = np.array_split(arr, 3)
print(newarr)
```

I got this error:

```py
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array'
```

(most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: I copied the lines you provide and get no error. Do you have more imports?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be the you probably have a file named `numpy.py` in your working directory. Since it has the same name as the module, it would shadow it would lead to this error. Rename that file and remove its numpy.pyc file.